# Creating cursor to connect to remote DB

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, cursor, dblink

Was trying to get the data from remote DB table via DB link in a procedure like my_procedure (DB_LINK).
How can I create cursor to connect with remote DB via this parameter in Oracle?

Comment: What is "this parameter"?

Comment: Hi, does your db have multiple **db_link**s? are they changing a lot?

Comment: I used dynamic sql to pass values to my original select statement in the cursor to solve above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that what you are asking is possible in the way you are describing it. The DB LINK is declared at the database level and I am not sure that it can be designated as a parameter directly. I could be wrong though.

We achieve similar results at my work by doing something like that :

```
   -- untested
   PROCEDURE my_procedure(target_db IN VARCHAR2) IS
   BEGIN
      IF target_db = 'database1' THEN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE myTable' || database1_dbLinkName ||
                           ' SET a = b WHERE x = z';
         NULL;
      ELSIF target_db = 'database2' THEN
         -- ...
         NULL;
      END IF;
   END;
```

I don't remember the exact syntaxe for the content of `database1_dbLinkName`. I believe it's just "@yourDbLinkName".

I recommend you read this page if you want to know more : https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4410488400346721382

Comment: Thanks. Dynamic sql helped to solve the above problem.